# Databricks error with dill module. It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation

Tags: save, databricks, dill

I am trying to a `scikit-learn`pipeline on Databricks. However, I encounter the following issue:

```
import dill
f = open("/dbfs/HR_pipe.p", mode='wb')
dill.dump(fitted,f)
```

where:

```
fitted = main_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Below you can find the error traceback, I am actually using scikit-learn version 0.24.2 and the class of the fitted object is a sklearn pipeline.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-97102145541341> in <module>
      1 import dill
      2 f = open("/dbfs/HR_pipe.p", mode='wb')
----> 3 dill.dump(fitted,f)

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1f8e9f3e-114d-4f9b-915f-25ba440655c4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py in dump(obj, file, protocol, byref, fmode, recurse, **kwds)
    334     _kwds = kwds.copy()
    335     _kwds.update(dict(byref=byref, fmode=fmode, recurse=recurse))
--> 336     Pickler(file, protocol, **_kwds).dump(obj)
    337     return
    338 

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1f8e9f3e-114d-4f9b-915f-25ba440655c4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py in dump(self, obj)
    618             raise PicklingError(msg)
    619         else:
--> 620             StockPickler.dump(self, obj)
    621         return
    622     dump.__doc__ = StockPickler.dump.__doc__

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in dump(self, obj)
    435         if self.proto >= 4:
    436             self.framer.start_framing()
--> 437         self.save(obj)
    438         self.write(STOP)
    439         self.framer.end_framing()

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    547 
    548         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 549         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    550 
    551     def persistent_id(self, obj):

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    660 
    661         if state is not None:
--> 662             save(state)
    663             write(BUILD)
    664 

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1f8e9f3e-114d-4f9b-915f-25ba440655c4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py in save_module_dict(pickler, obj)
   1249             # we only care about session the first pass thru
   1250             pickler._first_pass = False
-> 1251         StockPickler.save_dict(pickler, obj)
   1252         log.info("# D2")
   1253     return

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save_dict(self, obj)
    857 
    858         self.memoize(obj)
--> 859         self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
    860 
    861     dispatch[dict] = save_dict

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    883                 for k, v in tmp:
    884                     save(k)
--> 885                     save(v)
    886                 write(SETITEMS)
    887             elif n:

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save_list(self, obj)
    817 
    818         self.memoize(obj)
--> 819         self._batch_appends(obj)
    820 
    821     dispatch[list] = save_list

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in _batch_appends(self, items)
    841                 write(MARK)
    842                 for x in tmp:
--> 843                     save(x)
    844                 write(APPENDS)
    845             elif n:

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save_tuple(self, obj)
    772         if n <= 3 and self.proto >= 2:
    773             for element in obj:
--> 774                 save(element)
    775             # Subtle.  Same as in the big comment below.
    776             if id(obj) in memo:

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    547 
    548         # Save the reduce() output and finally memoize the object
--> 549         self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
    550 
    551     def persistent_id(self, obj):

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save_reduce(self, func, args, state, listitems, dictitems, obj)
    631                     "args[0] from __newobj__ args has the wrong class")
    632             args = args[1:]
--> 633             save(cls)
    634             save(args)
    635             write(NEWOBJ)

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    502         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
    503         if f is not None:
--> 504             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
    505             return
    506 

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1f8e9f3e-114d-4f9b-915f-25ba440655c4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py in save_type(pickler, obj, postproc_list)
   1838             _save_with_postproc(pickler, (_create_type, (
   1839                 type(obj), obj.__name__, obj.__bases__, _dict
-> 1840             )), obj=obj, postproc_list=postproc_list)
   1841             log.info("# %s" % _t)
   1842         else:

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1f8e9f3e-114d-4f9b-915f-25ba440655c4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py in _save_with_postproc(pickler, reduction, is_pickler_dill, obj, postproc_list)
   1152                 if source:
   1153                     pickler.write(pickler.get(pickler.memo[id(dest)][0]))
-> 1154                     pickler._batch_setitems(iter(source.items()))
   1155                 else:
   1156                     # Updating with an empty dictionary. Same as doing nothing.

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in _batch_setitems(self, items)
    883                 for k, v in tmp:
    884                     save(k)
--> 885                     save(v)
    886                 write(SETITEMS)
    887             elif n:

/usr/lib/python3.7/pickle.py in save(self, obj, save_persistent_id)
    522             reduce = getattr(obj, "__reduce_ex__", None)
    523             if reduce is not None:
--> 524                 rv = reduce(self.proto)
    525             else:
    526                 reduce = getattr(obj, "__reduce__", None)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/context.py in __getnewargs__(self)
    354         # This method is called when attempting to pickle SparkContext, which is always an error:
    355         raise Exception(
--> 356             "It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast "
    357             "variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, "
    358             "not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063."

Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Do you happen to know how to solve such issue?

details about the questions ..........................................................................

Comment: what error do you get? And please explain what you want to do

Comment: Basically I want to save a Scikit-learn fitted pipeline on Databricks so to use it for preprocessing data to score with a trained model. However, when I try to dump the fitted pipeline I obtain the following error:

**It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063**

Comment: Could you give us the complete traceback of the error and the class of the `fitted` object? Also which Python, `scikit-learn` and `dill` versions are you using? Did you change any of the `dill` settings or are you using defaults? If anyone can reproduce your problem, it may help to solve it.

Comment: I added the traceback error above. Moreover the pipeline object `fitted` is actually a Pipeline where customized transformers for data preparation have been used. '`dill == 0.3.5.1 `, while `sklearn== 0.24.2 `